# Wireless transmission multiple Arduinos to Raspberry Pi

Tags: sensor, wireless, arduino

I am fairly new to this, having worked only a bit with Arduinos. I would like to know if it would be possible to connect multiple Arduinos to a raspberry, just to transmit a signal.

Description:
A factory has 10 machines, I would like to connect an Arduino to each machine so that when the machines are on it would send a signal to the Raspberry Pi (or even another Arduino), and then it light up a tiny led lamp connected to the Raspberry Pi.
Whenever the machines are turned off, the led would turn off. Essentially, the Arduinos would probably be directly connected to the machines power supply in a way.

Would this be possible with multiple Arduinos and transmitters? I would say distances between the Arduinos and the Raspberry Pi would be between 20 to 70 meters.

Comment: Have a look at the ESP8266 or ESP32 modules and the use of MQTT.  These boards have built in wifi and MQTT allows short messages to be sent in a structured way between machines simply.  You could make the Pi an access point to keep this traffic away from the corporate network.

Comment: Thank you, will take a look at these.

Answer (score 1):

You can have several solutions for your problem.

**With an Access Point**

You can create a wireless network (with an Access Point you can also have a DHCP server giving IPs to the devices - The Raspberry PI or the Arduino receiving the signals should have a static IP address) and all the devices will connect to that access point.

**Using the Raspberry PI as an Access Point**

If you don't have an access point, the Raspberry PI can create a wireless network (an Ad-Hoc network to be precise) and all the devices would connect to that network, thus eliminating the need for the Access Point. This solution has some problems:

- The Raspberry PI must be in a central point for the network to be able to reach all the arduinos, but don't know if the Raspberry PI wireless card is strong enough

This should cover your connectivity issue.

The Raspberry PI has wireless integrated, but depending on the Arduinos of your choosing, you may or may not need to connect them to a wifi board

Hope it helps

NOTE: There's still other options like LoRa, but it requires separate cards for both Arduinos and Raspberry PI but I'm guessing that Wifi should be enough

Comment: Thank you, will look more into this.